# Unathorizing and removing DHCP role

Tags: windows-server-2008-r2, dhcp-server

I am removing DHCP from one of my server (Windows Server 2008 R2 Enterprise), besides running:

> netsh dhcp delete server *server name* *server IP*

and the removing DCHP role itself from Server Manager, anything else I need to worry about?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm making the assumption that you've exported your scopes and imported them on another server (if you even still need them) and/or some other server is handling the DHCP duties of the retired machine.

If the machine was a member of the "DOMAIN\DnsUpdateProxy" group you should probably remove it. Odds are good that it wasn't (because only certain configurations require that group membership) but it's worth checking.

Answer (score 2):

Other than ensuring that DHCP is still being served from somewhere else, and that your settings and scopes are intact on the other DHCP server, you mean?

Well, to echo my sentiments in the other thread, I'd worry about single-point-of-failure for DHCP.  You don't seem to be worried by that, though, so good luck, I guess.

And, you might want to try just powering the server off (or disconnecting from the network) before you actually delete the role.  To actually ensure everything still actually works on your new single-point-of-failure DHCP solution.

Comment: we have 2 other DCHP servers running

Comment: Good to know.  You still probably want to verify all the scopes and settings are duplicated elsewhere, and see what happens to DHCP when you disconnect it, in case this particular DHCP server is the only one holding certain DHCP scopes.